# Access 'PasswordNeverExpires' property in Azure AD via C#

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I have the below code C# which works great for querying Azure AD but I need to also read in the property  'PasswordNeverExpires' as shown in the below screenshot. I cannot see the property on the full MS list here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0 - only a 'passwordPolicies' property which returns "DisablePasswordExpiration" for all our users which doesn't tally up with the results shown in AD manager. I can see plenty of powershell scripts, for example here - https://serverfault.com/questions/730189/powershell-find-all-users-with-password-never-expires - which mention a 'passwordNeverExpires' property but this only appears blank when I run my C# script.

```
 string Url = $"{config.ApiUrl}v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordNeverExpires";
                do {
                    string JSON = await apiCaller.CallWebApiAndProcessResultASync(Url, result.AccessToken, Display);
                
                    Url = AADR.OdataNextLink;
                } while (AADR.OdataNextLink != null);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The powershell scripts you found in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/730189/powershell-find-all-users-with-password-never-expires) is for AD rather than AAD. So it doesn't work for AAD. There is not a property named `PasswordNeverExpires` in AAD Module.

**PowerShell Script:**

You can use the following PowerShell cmdlet to see if a single user's password is set to never expire (reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/set-password-to-never-expire?view=o365-worldwide#how-to-check-the-expiration-policy-for-a-password)):

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId <user id or UPN> | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
    N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}
}
```

The cmdlet aliases `PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"` to a new property `PasswordNeverExpires`.

To see the Password never expires setting for all users, run the following cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
    N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}
 }
```

**Microsoft Graph:**

Since there is no `PasswordNeverExpires` property in MS Graph [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0), you should just query the `passwordPolicies` property using MS Graph.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime,passwordPolicies
```

Then you will get `"passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"` in the response. Use your own code logic to handle it (define a `PasswordNeverExpires` and set it to `true`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried passwordPolicies but 'DisablePasswordExpiration' is replied for every user whether they have 'password never expires' ticked or not in AD manager

Comment: @DavidLindon For "AD manager", can you share a link (maybe a download url) about it so that I can have a test?

Comment: it is the first screenshot. I've spoken to the network admin and it appears that option isn't sent to sync to AAD